# How to get server side hash generation URL in PayUMoney

Tags: android, production, payumoney

I have integrated PayUMoney in my app using https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App but there is need to add some URL in MainActivity like

```
//TODO Below url is just for testing purpose, merchant needs to replace this with their server side hash generation url
                URL url = new URL("https://payu.herokuapp.com/get_hash");
```

and also

```
//TODO Deploy a file on your server for storing cardToken and merchantHash nad replace below url with your server side file url.
                    URL url = new URL("https://payu.herokuapp.com/store_merchant_hash");
```

in storeMerchantHash Function

```
//TODO Replace below url with your server side file url.
                    URL url = new URL("https://payu.herokuapp.com/get_merchant_hashes");
```

in fetchMerchantHashes function.
These type number of url, How i can get it?
    I am not getting how to get this URL, kindly guide me.

Comment: Any one have an idea?

Comment: You need to add a web API in your own server for hash calculation. As documentation states : https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/webcheckout/redirect.html#server-side .  There are some sample kits available for the API in their documentation in various frameworks.